# Average of grouped data in column using Sequelize

Tags: average, sequelize.js

I'm trying to find the average of a 'ratings' column for all the data that has the same 'VenueId'. I have it working with raw code but need to adapt it in Sequelize. The working raw code is

```
SELECT venueId, AVG(rating) AS average FROM reviews GROUP BY VenueId
```

The code I've tried is

```
Review.findAll({
    order: [[Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('rating'))]]
}).then(function(Venues) {})
```

I'm getting an error:

> Executing (default): SELECT id, review, rating, createdAt, updatedAt,
>   VenueId FROM Reviews AS Review ORDER BY max(rating); Unhandled
>   rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT:
>   Expression #1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to
>   the result of a non-aggregated query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

This might need some tweaking as I don't know your models, but I suggest you try the following:

```
Review.findAll({
   attributes: ['venueId', [models.sequelize.fn('AVG', models.sequelize.col('venue_id')), 'venueIdCount']],
   group: 'venue_id'
   order: [[models.sequelize.fn('AVG', models.sequelize.col('venue_id')), 'DESC']]
}).then(function() {
   //Do something
}})
```

Important to notice: When I use "venueId" I mean the name of the attribute on your model, and when I use "venue_id" I mean the name of the column in your database table. They might be the same or different, so feel free to tweak it.

Answer (score 3):

You must do this

```
Review.findAll({
    attributes: ['venueId', [models.sequelize.fn('AVG', 
    models.sequelize.col('rating')), 'ratingAvg']],
    group: ['venueId'],
    order: [[models.sequelize.fn('AVG', models.sequelize.col('rating')), 'DESC']]
}).then(function() {
    //Do something
}})
```

Or this with async/await

```
async(() => {
    return await(Review.findAll({
        attributes: ['venueId', [models.sequelize.fn('AVG', 
        models.sequelize.col('rating')), 'ratingAvg']],
        group: ['venueId'],
        order: [[models.sequelize.fn('AVG', models.sequelize.col('rating')), 'DESC']]}))
})
```