# How to pass query params into sequelize when params describe relations

Tags: api, express, sequelize.js

For instance, I have model `Student` and a couple of models that relates to it. Let it be `Class`, `Absence` and `Grade`.

Definitions for this models:

```
var Student = sequelize.define('Student', {
    class_id : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    name : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    gender : DataTypes.ENUM('male', 'female')
    is_paid : DataTypes.BOOLEAN
})

var Class = sequelize.define('Class', {
    name : DataTypes.STRING
})

var Absense = sequelize.define('Absense', {
    student_id : DataTypes.INTEGER
    date : DataTypes.DATEONLY,
})

var Grade = sequelize.define('Grade', {
    student_id : 
    subject : DataTypes.ENUM('singing', 'dancing')
    value : DataTypes.INTEGER
})

Absense.belongsTo(Student, { foreign_key : 'student_id' });
Grade.belongsTo(Student, { foreign_key : 'student_id' })
```

I want to add endpoint to list entities for this model. But also I want to allow to use optional filters in this endpoint.
So both of this usages will be possible:

- `GET api.acme.com/v0.1/users`
- `GET api.acme.com/v0.1/users?
        class=1,3
       &gender=male
       &is_paid=true
       &absences=true
       &avg_grade=gt:3
       &limit=20&offset=0&order=avg_grade%20DESC`

While I handle params that present in `Student`, it's easy:

```
var condition = {};

req.params.is_paid && condition.is_paid = boolean(req.params.is_paid);
req.params.gender && condition.gender = { $in : req.params.gender.split(',') };
req.params.class && condition.class = { $in : req.params.class.split(',') };

res.json(await Student.findAll({
    where : condition,
    limit : req.query.limit || 20,
    offset : req.query.offset || 0,
    order : req.query.order || 'id ASC'
}))
```

But when I want to add implement `absense` or `avg_grade` filter, I have to step down from sequelize and write raw query for this that turns to be huge.

Right now I'm thinking about creating special `students_expanded` view for this, but I want to be sure, I'm not missing anything. Is there any way to do this using Sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `include` object with the requested model and filter and set `required: true` on it.

The following would show all students with an absence:

```
Student.findAll({
    where : condition,
    limit : req.query.limit || 20,
    offset : req.query.offset || 0,
    order : req.query.order || 'id ASC'
    include: {
        model: Absense,
        required: true
    }
}))
```

The average grade is trickier, because you need to aggregate the grades to get the average - see [Average of grouped data in column using Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35807484/4887407)